# issue while loading jquery cropzee function in magento2

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation, magento2, crop

This is my html file

```
 require(['jquery','croppr','canvastoblob','FileSaver'],
  function($,croppr,canvastoblob,FileSaver){

$(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#crop").cropzee();
});

var defaultWidth = 210;
$.fn.extend({
    cropzee: function (options = {
    aspectRatio: null,
            maxSize: null,
            minSize: null,
            startSize: [100, 100, '%'],
           .....
           ......
           })
        })
```

While loading this page show an error in the console like this

> index:373 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).cropzee is not a function

Is there any error in the function call or somewhere else?
anybody, please help me to fix this error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this code before end of the file.Fix my issue.

```
 $("#crop").cropzee();
});
```